# Multiple config transforms within team city build

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, slowcheetah

I would like to perform the config transform for multiple environments upon Team City build. Essentially I would like to transform my config file for dev, test and live as part of a single TC build.
I was hoping I would be able to use Slow Cheetah as part of an extra build step within team city however I don't really know an awful lot about Slow Cheetah.

Has anyone come across this issue or something similar before?

Cheers Dee

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an article which describes what your looking for:

[Slow Cheetah Build Server Support Updated](http://sedodream.com/2012/12/24/SlowCheetahBuildServerSupportUpdated.aspx)

Comment: add the relevant details from the link into the answer. Link only answers are not allowed.